# How do I get label, placeholder or id instead of name from $key in foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){

Tags: php, email, post

I have dynamic field names that are being posted to my mail processor. I need to get the label, placeholder or id instead of the name from the following form:

```
<label for='name' >Nombre</label>
<input type='text' class="form-control" name='name' id='Nombre' value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('name') ?>' placeholder="Nombre" />
```

This is the code:

```
$ret_str='';
        foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
        {
            if(!$this->IsInternalVariable($key))
            {
                $value = htmlentities($value,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
                $value = nl2br($value);
                $key = ucfirst($key);
                $ret_str .= "<p>$key: $value\n</p>";
            }
        }
return $ret_str;
```

But this is the result:

```
Name: Example
```

Answer (score 1):

That information isn't passed via POST. Only the name/value pair is passed. If you want other information, you will have to pass it explicitly.

Comment: And how can I pass it explicitly?

Comment: @DavidM you need to use AJAX and/or hidden fields.